# Java socket Basic WWW-Authentication

Tags: java, sockets, basic-authentication, request-headers, www-authenticate

I want to authenticate a socket connection in the Web browser by using the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header but no prompt for username and password comes up. How do go about it?

```java
   public static void responseView(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        responseHeaders(200);
        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        for(String header : headers) {
            outputStream.writeBytes(header + "\r\n");
        }
        outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
        outputStream.writeBytes("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Java Web Server</title></head><body></body></html>");
        outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
        outputStream.flush();
    }
    
    public static void responseHeaders(int statusCode) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
        headers.add("HTTP/1.0 " + Integer.toString(statusCode) + " " + Config.STATUS_CODES.get(statusCode));
        headers.add("Content-Type: text/html");
        headers.add("Date: " + formatter.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
        headers.add("Server: Simple Java Web Server");
        headers.add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic");
    }
```

Comment: *...but no prompt for username and password comes up...* Where is there a prompt anywhere in your code?

Comment: You won't get that functionality in the `Socket` API.  You have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to authenticate a socket connection in the Web browser

Basic access authentication does not authenticate a socket connection, but a HTTP request. There can be multiple HTTP requests inside a single underlying socket connection, with different or with no authentication. And requesting authentication and sending the authenticated request can be done in different connections.

> ```
>    responseHeaders(200);
> ```

The status code when requesting authentication must be 401, not 200

> ```
>    headers.add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic");
> ```

The `WWW-Authenticate` header must contain the `realm` attribute to show the user what the authentication is for.

For a short overview about the topic see [Wikipedia: Basic access authentication: Server side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side). The ultimate reference is [the standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235#section-4.1) though.